# How to run Mongo Shell Query directly from PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to run MongoDB raw query directly from PHP.

My query is like below.

```
var document_id = db.Document.aggregate([{$project: {"creationDate":1,'_id':1}},{$match: {"_id":ObjectID("5aa7a8852f4b3e2e86004837")}}]).toArray();

document_id = document_id[0]['_id'];

var upload_id = db.Upload.aggregate([{$project: {"creationDate":1,'_id':1}},{$match: {"_id":ObjectID("5aa7a8852f4b3e2e86004837")}}]).toArray();

upload_id = upload_id[0]['_id'];
```

and get result of those two variable document_id & upload_id of concat or multiple or addition.

> ( FYI: In real, I won't concat or multiply ids it is just for example. )

I have checked "http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongodb.php" for reference but nothing found useful.

Can anyone guide me on that ?

**Version of MongoDB & PHP MongoDB driver I am using.**

MongoDB version 3.6

MongoDB PHP Driver version 1.5

Comment: As per docs extension should be used with a high level library like https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library - check its docs on how to run aggregation queries

Comment: @malarzm Thanks! I guess I have checked there too. but will do that again. Incase I missed something.

Comment: Any news on that? I too want to run a Mongo Shell Query directly, instead of converting to a high level query.

Comment: @pagliuca : It wasn't worked for me at that time. I have tried most of every way I can follow. In case you find any way in future or not please share it with me also.